# can you make a list of differents element in java without making a class for it

Tags: java, spring-boot

i need a create a list that contains in each iteration an  int ,date and a note (String)

so what i need is something like this :
List A ={[5,12/12/2020, "note1"],[6,11/01/2021,"note2"],...}
what i need is the declaration for this . and i knew that i can change it to a list<list< String >> then change everything back from String to the type of thing that i want or declare a class that contains that information and make a list of that class but what i'm asking is there a way to make without doing that (without changing to String and without declaring a new class) .
thank you for any help you offer

Comment: Ideally you should create your own class, but as you don't want to do that (not sure why) you can use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/ImmutableTriple.html

Comment: Why exactly do you not want to make a class? That's the way it is done in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
List<Object[]> lista = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

    lista.add(new Object[] {5, LocalDate.of(12,12,2020),  "note1"});
    lista.add(new Object[] {6, LocalDate.of(11,1,2021),  "note2"});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't *think* what you want is possible, at least not exactly the way you want it.

According to the the Java SE API, a `List` is "An ordered collection" and a `Collection` "represents a group of objects, known as its *elements*". See [List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)
and/or [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html).

Each "element" of a `List` can only be a single object, so having an element that's actually "3" separate entities goes against its implementation.

But as you pointed out, that object element can contain whatever you want. But as you said, that's not a viable option in your case unfortunately.

I'm sure someone with more knowledge of Java can possibly suggest some method to achieve what you want, but I have a feeling at that point you'd be creating a hack to circumvent some of the core functionality of the`List` implementation, in which case using a `List` may not be the best route.

It sounds like you're describing a `List` where each *element* contains an `int`, a `Date`, and a `String`. So, creating a class that contains those 3 properties that can then be used as each object element of the `List` would be utilizing the `List`'s implementation correctly as opposed to trying to make it do something it's not intended to do.

But I'm curious to see what others say and hope they can provide more help than I'm capable of providing! Good luck!

Comment: so what i was thinking is that in case i wanted to change this class to history of anything in the database so i would need  (like date  of the action , the action and  the id of who did that action) so making a class where i would store this in the data base does make it crumpy and feels a lot of waste of space , so i was thinking maybe there is a way to limite that wasted space  . well thanks you for the help and thanks to everyone else

Comment: @IradAmri Sounds like you're worrying about a preoptimization which I'm definitely guilty of doing, we all are at times :). The class you'd make would simply be a container for 1 primitive (an int), and 2 objects (a Date and String). Even if you found a way to create a List where each element contained those 3 things, they'd still exist in memory regardless, the class you'd make is simply a wrapper class containing those 3 things. So creating a class for them wouldn't really be wasting any space so I'd say, try to not worry about it unless you identify a bottleneck.

Comment: In my current graduation project i already implimented a solution what i'm curious about was what if i can't change the database as i like what if it was a big database like a bank orsomzthing similar where every bit counts.

Comment: So i wanted to try and find a generic solution. For exemple what if i'm doing a documents history like modification date if there was a  problem or a complain throught the complains table response from mail.. Etc that would make a lot of relations and an excess in useless data what if i can change all that into a simple element which contains all and without changing currznt table adding just one table without changing the rest ( for exemple if this was a company or something similar you can't change the database as you like and if changed problems might happen)

Comment: btw i'm the kind of people who even if can get a solution for the current problem i would try to look for similar bigger problem and try to find a way,  well thank you for your time again.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Collections to just store Objects, so you can stuff pretty much anything you want in there then pull it out later. This is Not Recommended(tm).

```
import java.util.*;

public class Rando
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List<Object> randomStuff = new ArrayList<>();

        randomStuff.add(1);
        randomStuff.add(new Date());
        randomStuff.add("A note");

        System.out.println(randomStuff);

        Map<String, Object> randomMap = new HashMap<>();

        randomMap.put("id", 1);
        randomMap.put("date", new Date());
        randomMap.put("note", "This is another note");

        System.out.println(randomMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an option (and not a good one as you pointed out), but the asker wants each element of the List to contain those three properties (int, Date, String). In the above example each property is its own element.

Comment: Right, you would populate a record in either of those ways in a loop and stick them in some outer collection.

Comment: Ah, so you mean it'd end up being a 2 dimensional List where each element is its own List containing the 3 properties the asker wants?

Comment: Correct, I should have taken the time to indicate that. In interpreted the question to be more about how to store things in a generic container without specifying their type.

Comment: What you suggested is I think more close to what the asker wants than I initially thought. As each List element (not the List of Lists) would contain the 3 different types of objects they need. Still though, it just does not seem like a good idea (but does answer their question and you point out it's not recommended)